# Phabricator: Error "ARC: Cannot mix D and F" when do arc diff

Tags: linux, git, phabricator, arcanist

I did a commit and after trying to crate a diff with
`arc diff dev` command but I've got an error
`ARC: Cannot mix D and F
UNIX: No such file or directory`

Any ideas how to solve it?

The steps I did before arc diff command:

```
$ git commit -am "<commit message>" 
$ git pull --rebase
$ git push origin my_working_branch
```

The git status output:

```
$ git status
On branch ATD-86
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
../javaproject/ 
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to 
track)
```

The branch dev is protected, could it be a reason?

Answer (score 0):

This error message seems to come from the `arc` command at https://github.com/hyc/arc/

This is not the arc command you want for using Phabricator's arcanist.  Try `export PATH=/path/to/arcansit/bin:$PATH` to prepend arcanist to your path before that foreign arc command, or use `alias arc='/path/to/arcanist/bin/arc'` to force the correct `arc` command.